Different shitos in halachah
If one holds like a certain shita in halachah. Then acts in accordance to a different shita in halachah, other then what he holds.
is his action valid because there is still some shitos in halachah like that, or no, because he didn't do according to the shita he holds of in halachah?

Isn't that precisely what R' Yehoshua was praised for doing by appearing in public with his wallet on the day he felt was Yom Kippur, but the establishment said was not?

Thats maybe because beis din paskined like that so he needed to do like that. but what about when there are 2 equal shitos in halachah and you hold like one while at the same you did like the other. in that case is your action still valid?

Can the OP or ( @Kirk ) provide an example of the sort of case they have in mind by holds like a certain shita . . . acts in accordance to a different shita . . . is his action valid

I would imagine an example could be an Ashkenazi  Jew who holds that opening bottle caps on Shabbat is prohibited but opening one (holding which is  generally held by Sephardic poskim) @EdwardB because of extenuating circumstances

It would depend if you hold you are doing basic halacha or a stringency. If you hold it's completely assur to do something then you cannot tell another Jew to do it because it's lifnei iver.
For example if you hold Rabbenu Tam is law then can't tell others to break Shabbat for you or do any leniencies during that "extra" time but if you hold it's just a chumra and we go like the geonim then many different leniencies can apply. Another example would be regarding bracha levatala where Chacham Ovadia says you cannot even answer Amen to an Ashkenzi's bracha since YOU hold it's a bracha levatala.
I've seen this in writing in regards to soda bottles but I forgot in which sefer.

Something along these lines actually came up for me this past Friday night. The minyan I davened with starts almost an hour before sunset, for historical reasons that aren't completely clear to me. My father and I were invited to dinner on a higher floor, but he wasn't comfortable taking the stairs the whole way up, so he didn't daven ma'ariv with the minyan. As such, he used the elevator to go up and, since it was before he had accepted Shabbat, I went along for the ride
